# What's the difference between PRINT and PRINT() in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

At first I thought brackets in SQL do not matter, until today I learned `EXEC` and `EXEC()` are totally different things: one calls a stored procedure, the other executes a string as a command.

What's the difference between `PRINT` and `PRINT()`, if any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between `PRINT and PRINT()` and both will yield you the same results unlike `exec`

`print 1 and print (1)` both are same.

And You cannot add any parameters in here as like exec!!